# Falta revisar la traducción de una cadena en la guía avanzada de Markdown

Tags: bug, estado-completado, traducida-falta-revisar

En https://es.stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code se muestra en inglés una cadena la cual ya está traducida en Transifex pero está pendiente de revisar.

Enlace a Transifex sobre la cadena en cuestión

[The text will be wrapped in tags, and displayed in…](https://www.transifex.com/stack-exchange/stack-overflow-es/translate/#es/english/134814910?key=ed515019a4f1b246b96626dfbb218c60)

Comment: Parece que esto ya está solucionado, ¿no?

Comment: @fedorqui Sí, bien visto.

Comment: Perfecto. Estaba revisando todas las [preguntas de Bug sin estado-* y abiertas](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=is%3Aq+%5Bbug%5D+closed%3Ano+-%5Bestado-*%5D) :)